# How to store a small Confidential file in PCF so that a Spring boot App can access it

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have to store my Kafka `Keystore.jks` and `Truststore.jks` file in PCF so that my spring boot app runs there can use it to access the cluster.

The solution that I have in my mind is as follows.
My Jenkins pipeline is hooked up to Hashicorp Vault. So I can keep the BASE64 encoded content in Vault and read it from there during the deployment. But I don't know how to dump that content as a file in PCF VM before my Java app starts. I tried to pursue `.profile` route; unfortunately Java Build pack doesn't support `.profile`. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: FYI, the Java buildpack doesn't have to support anything for `.profile` files to work. That functionality is provided by the platform lifecycle. What's tricky with Java apps is getting the `.profile` script into the correct location. It needs to be in the root of what you push to PCF, thus it needs to be at the root of your WAR/JAR file. If you run `jar tf <file>`, you can see the contents and confirm it's location. It should not be within any folders. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options:

1. Put your JKS files which are password protected as a file inside your app. Pass in the password to read them using an environment variable, user provided service, via Spring Config Server or via CredHub service broker.
2. Same as #1, but create a small custom buildpack that installs your JKS files. Use the platforms multi-buildpack functionality to run your custom buildpack first and Java buildpack second. This option is a little more convenient if you have lots of apps using the same JKS files.
3. Base64 encode your JKS files and stuff them into an environment variable, user provided service, Spring Config Server or via CredHub service broker. Retrieve & decode them as your app starts, either in a `.profile` file or in the app itself.

When building your JAR file, you can run run `jar uf <path/to/file.jar> .profile` and it will add the `.profile` file to the root of your JAR.

You can confirm it's in the right place by running `jar tf <path/to/file.jar>`. The output should look like this...

```
...
BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
<rest of your files here>
... 
.profile
```

Note how there is no path in front of `.profile`. That's where it needs to be to work properly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. QQns: Are you sure about .profile. I tried to put it in the location from where I ran the cf push. also I tried to put it in the same directory as that of my jar file (./build/lib). None of that worked.
Also do you have example of simple custom buildpack?

Comment: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profile -- Here it says Java buildpack is not supported

Comment: It definitely works, I use it occasionally for troubleshooting. I don't know why that's in our docs, I've asked to have it changed as it's misleading but no luck. What is being said on the Github issue is that it's difficult to get right & that it's not recommend, not that it doesn't work.

Comment: For a Java app, the `.profile` file needs to be actually in the JAR file. Not in the directory with the JAR and not at the root of our source code. Java is different from other languages on CF in that you push compiled code, not source code. Thus what get's pushed is the contents of your JAR/WAR *only*. If you put the `.profile` file in the JAR not under any folder then it will work. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: As you suggested, option 2 seems ideal to me too. I don't really want to expose my JKS files even if its password protected, because it's application specific and supposed to be a secret. So that rules out option 1. I would proceed with option 3 for now. I will change to option 2 as I am getting familiar with buildpacks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `spring-cloud-vault` plugin to let spring-boot bootstrap your secrets from vault on application startup.
[Spring-cloud-vault plugin](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/)

But I dont understand why you need to put your JKS files in vault.
These JKS files are password protected, which means you can bundle the jks files as a resource inside your JAR and just get the secret password you need to open these JKS files from vault, on application startup

Comment: Thank you. Let's just say I want a secret file in the filesystem (mount or local, I don't really mind). Obviously I don't want to checkin that to my code version control system. It's a basic usecase that any platform should support. K8s had it even in the earlier version.

Comment: similarly I cannot/or rather I don't want to include that in the jar as its more of environment dependent (because my staging might be talking to a different kafka cluster than that of prod)

Answer (score 1):

I've created a new supply buildpack to help solve this

https://github.com/starkandwayne/dot-profile-buildpack

```
cf push javaapp --path build/jibs/myapp-1.0.0.jar \
  -b https://github.com/starkandwayne/dot-profile-buildpack \
  -b java_buildpack \
  --no-start
cf set-env javaapp PROFILED "$(cat <<SHELL
#!/bin/bash

cat > config.json <<JSON
{
  "some": "config"
}
JSON
SHELL
)"
cf start javaapp
```

Of course, you could also set the `$PROFILED` env var within your `cf push -f manifest.yml`.